# .net core MVC Month schedule for punching in and out cant store days in database using entityframework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to generate a view with all days of a month like this image below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pJvxXeajDnL7_W4VT4CNAQy_lONhRwf9/view?usp=sharing

here is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

#nullable disable

namespace abcs.Models
{
    public partial class PunchIn
    {
        public uint Pid { get; set; }
        public int? Year { get; set; }
        public int? Month { get; set; }
        [Range(1,31,ErrorMessage ="days range is from 1 to 31")]
        public int? Day { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "punch in time")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? PunchIn1 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "puch out time")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime? PunchOut { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "remark")]
        public string Remark2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here is my controller

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
          return View();
        }
    
     [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Pid,Year,Month,Day,PunchIn1,PunchOut,Remark2")] PunchIn punchIn)
        {
            ViewBag.Year = punchIn.Year;


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(punchIn);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(punchIn);
        }
```

here is my view:

```
@model abcs.Models.PunchIn

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<style>
    tr {
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        color: white;
    }

    table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
</style>

<form asp-action="Create">
    
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Punch in time
                </th>
                <th>
                    Puncn out time
                </th>
                <th>
                    remark
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                int year = 2022;
                for (int month = 1; month <= 1; month++)
                {
                        <h2 align="center">@year @month Month</h2>
                    int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
                    for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++)
                    {
                        DateTime weekday = new DateTime(year, month, day);

                        <tr>                           
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @day
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Day" value="@day" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input asp-for="PunchIn1" class="form-control" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="PunchIn1" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input asp-for="PunchOut" class="form-control" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="PunchOut" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input asp-for="Remark2" class="form-control" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Remark2" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </tbody>
 
    </table>
</form>
```

When I create a form, I can't recieve day value, how to send day value to database?Thank you.
In addition, I write date from Front-end view instead of using controller(postend), but is there a better way?How can I create correct days list based on select month and year in other ways with controller coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the value of "day" in your form,so you couldn't get it in your controller ,try with:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
        .........
      <div class="form-group">
       @day
       <input asp-for="Day" class="form-control" value=@day hidden/>
       <span asp-validation-for="Day" value="@day" class="text-danger"></span>
       </div>
      .......
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>

</form>
```

I tried as below:

```
@{
    int year = 2022;
    int month = 3;
    int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>PunchIn</h4>
<hr />
<h2 align="center">@year @month Month</h2>
<form asp-action="Create">

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Punch in time
                </th>
                <th>
                    Puncn out time
                </th>
                <th>
                    remark
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>           
            
            @for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++)
            {           

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @day
                        <input name =PunchIn[@(day-1)].Day asp-for="Day" class="form-control" value=@day hidden />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Day" value="@day" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name =PunchIn[@(day-1)].PunchIn1 asp-for="PunchIn1" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="PunchIn1" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name =PunchIn[@(day-1)].PunchOut asp-for="PunchOut" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="PunchOut" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name =PunchIn[@(day-1)].Remark2 asp-for="Remark2" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Remark2" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }            
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </tbody>

    </table>
</form>
```

In controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create( List<PunchIn> PunchIn)
        {
           
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var targetlist=PunchIn.Where(x => x.PunchIn1 != null).ToList();                
                _context.AddRange(targetlist);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            
            return View();
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but when I add input code above, I key 6th and related data and submit, only show 1th day rather than 6th day. Besides, punch in and punch out time which I key in is null value.  the problem like this image below :(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qebVUmH-AA6DO0lf-cacJkCWopzWcLoF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Colette   It  was because when you submit your form,you submit all records in your form,and the elements in the list have the same name ,so you could only get the value of the fist record (you submited a list in your frontend but you just need an element in your backend),So what you want?PunchIn or List<PunchIn>?

Comment: Thank you Ruikai Feng, I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it

Comment: It works. Thank you for your answer about coding which is brilliant.  I really appreciate that.

Comment: If I want to add dropdownlist for Year and month,  the below value will change based on selected year and month. How can I change it?   Like the image below(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ucjmRjnXIltr7mvrtWeGweSg9PZT4QGo/view?usp=sharing) Thank you.  @Ruikai Feng
I add year and month using readonly="readonly"  view

Comment: @Colette I think it's better to create a mothpicker  rather than two selectlist,you could try to search the js codes and file related ,it may take much time for us to write it ourselves.if you do want to write the codes yourself,I could try it for you tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try use mothpicker with JS code.
@Ruikai Feng

Comment: I found an example on github:https://github.com/xiaoshengxianjun/month-picker/tree/master/month-picker and you could write the js codes,when you click the mothpicker, change the value of the input textbox  like:   .click(function () { inputvalue = $("#xx").val();})

Comment: Thank you. When I  try, it appears error about: jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).MonthPicker is not a function TypeError: $(...).MonthPicker is not a function. How can I alter?

Comment: Please would you do me a favor by writing the codes.  Like the image below(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ucjmRjnXIltr7mvrtWeGweSg9PZT4QGo/view) If it's better to use monthpicker with js, can you provide me codes to refer to. Thank you. @Ruikai Feng

Comment: I've ansewered your question in your another case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72374324/net-core-mvc-month-schedule-dropdownlist-for-year-and-month-the-below-value-wi

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate that. I have a problem to mention on above case.