# .net core MVC Month schedule dropdownlist for Year and month, the below value will change based on selected year and month for using entityframework

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

My code is like this Link:([.net core MVC Month schedule for punching in and out cant store days in database using entityframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72345007/net-core-mvc-month-schedule-for-punching-in-and-out-cant-store-days-in-database))
I want to add function like this image(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ucjmRjnXIltr7mvrtWeGweSg9PZT4QGo/view)
In my view, I add year and month.

```
                       <td>
                            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name=PunchIn[@(day-1)].Year asp-for="Year" class="form-control" value=@year readonly="readonly" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Year" value="@year" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name=PunchIn[@(day-1)].Month asp-for="Month" class="form-control" value=@month readonly="readonly" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Month" value="@month" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

How can I add year and month dropdownlist? Is there a better way with altering view from Front-end or altering controller(postend)? When I select year and month, the first day to the last day of a month about year and month value will simultaneously change. In addition,  when submiting the form, I can store the form, which I fill in, in the database.

Here is my dropdownlist with month and year:
However, when I add the view, it will show failure. How can I add this to solve above proble?Or there is another better way? Thank you.

```
var years = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (var i = 2020; i <= 2042; i++)
    {
        years.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = Model.Year == i });
    }

 var months = new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "1", Value = "1", Selected = Model.Month == 1},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "2", Value = "2", Selected = Model.Month == 2},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "3", Value = "3", Selected = Model.Month == 3},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "4", Value = "4", Selected = Model.Month == 4},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "5", Value = "5", Selected = Model.Month == 5},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "6", Value = "6", Selected = Model.Month == 6},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "7", Value = "7", Selected = Model.Month == 7},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "8", Value = "8", Selected = Model.Month == 8},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "9", Value = "9", Selected = Model.Month == 9},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "10", Value = "10", Selected = Model.Month == 10},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "11", Value = "11", Selected = Model.Month == 11},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "12", Value = "12", Selected = Model.Month == 12},
     };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused with  the attribute "Selected",If you set true,it will become the default option of your selectlist
I tried to modify  your codes as below:

```
@{
    int year = 2022;
    int month = 3;
    int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

    var months = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem {Text = "1", Value = "1"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "2", Value = "2"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "3", Value = "3",Selected=true},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "4", Value = "4"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "5", Value = "5"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "6", Value = "6"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "7", Value = "7"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "8", Value = "8"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "9", Value = "9"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "10", Value = "10"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "11", Value = "11"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "12", Value = "12"},
    };
}
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        // initialize the value of the input field to the selected value


        $('.Month').val($('#selectlist').val());

        $('#selectlist').change(function () {
            // when the value of the dropdown list changes
            // update the input field
            var month = $(this).val();
            console.log(month);
            $("#titlemonth").text($(this).val());
            $('.Month').val($(this).val());
           
            $(document).find("tr[id='PunchIn[30]']").remove();
            if ((month == 1) || (month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) || (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12))
            {
                $(document).find("table[id=test]").append('<tr id="PunchIn[30]"><td><div class="form-group"><input name="PunchIn[30].Month" class="Month" value="" type="number" id="Month" /></div><div class="form-group"><a name="31">31</a><input name="PunchIn[30].Day" class="form-control" value="31" hidden type="number" id="Day" /><span value="31" class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Day" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div></td><td><div class="form-group"><input name="PunchIn[30].PunchIn1" class="form-control" type="time" id="PunchIn1" value="" /><span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PunchIn1" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div></td><td><div class="form-group"><input name="PunchIn[30].PunchOut" class="form-control" type="time" id="PunchOut" value="" /><span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PunchOut" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div></td><td><div class="form-group"><input name="PunchIn[30].Remark2" class="form-control" type="text" id="Remark2" value="" /><span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Remark2" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div></td></tr>');
               
            }
            
            
            
        });
        
    });


</script>



<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>PunchIn</h4>
<hr />
<select id="selectlist" asp-items=months></select>
<h2 align="center">@year <a id="titlemonth">@month</a> Month</h2>
<form asp-action="Create">

    <table class="table"id="test">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Punch in time
                </th>
                <th>
                    Puncn out time
                </th>
                <th>
                    remark
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >

            @for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++)
            {

                <tr id="PunchIn[@(day-1)]">

                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name=PunchIn[@(day-1)].Month asp-for="Month" class="Month" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a name="@day">@day</a>
                            <input name=PunchIn[@(day-1)].Day asp-for="Day" class="form-control" value=@day hidden />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Day" value="@day" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name=PunchIn[@(day-1)].PunchIn1 asp-for="PunchIn1" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="PunchIn1" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name=PunchIn[@(day-1)].PunchOut asp-for="PunchOut" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="PunchOut" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name=PunchIn[@(day-1)].Remark2 asp-for="Remark2" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Remark2" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            }
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </tbody>

    </table>
</form>
```

Result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate that. But I have a question, when I add this to my controller, like this below(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IXY0g7vceEa26L6CCx6Qkde3JCA19CXx/view?usp=sharing),and view I alter as the image.(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NUYtc_eUyvdZf-DYuOHSri2vmYfa4Jhg/view?usp=sharing) I can't get correct day, day always 30 days no matter which month I choose. Like March with 31 days, but it shows only 30 days. How can I fix it? It seems that it can't read month with js,  I saw you limit 31 days with January, March and etc. thank you. @Ruikai Feng

Comment: @Colette The codes I posted yesterday still has some logical need to be added,I ‘ve updated  and it could work well now

Comment: It works, and the append methd is interesting. I’m very grateful for your amazing codes, I really learned a lot about it. @Ruikai Feng